# SQLite / .Net FTS tables causing odd error

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I have a very simple database, but added an FTS table for faster text searching:

```
CREATE TABLE appEntries (Created TEXT, SizeOnDisk INTEGER, IsPath INTEGER, Drive TEXT, Path TEXT, Name TEXT, Extension TEXT, Size INTEGER, Modified TEXT)
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE appEntriesText USING fts5 (Path, Name)
```

When I go to do an insert from my .Net code:

```
CommandText = "Insert Into appEntries (IsPath, Drive, Path, Extension, Size, Modified, Created, SizeOnDisk) 
VALUES (@IsPath, @Drive, @Path, @Extension, @Size, @Modified, @Created, @SizeOnDisk)"
```

I get a lovely error:

```
malformed database schema (appEntriesText_config) - near "WITHOUT": syntax error
```

Pulling up DB Browser for SQLite:

I see:

```
CREATE TABLE 'appEntriesText_config'(k PRIMARY KEY, v) WITHOUT ROWID
```

I run
`PRAGMA integrity_check`

and nothing is wrong...